# How to select the remaining rows after selected some in Android SQLite?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have a task in which i have to display the rows selected using a query in one tab and the remaining rows in another tab. I have displayed the selected rows using `SimpleCursorAdapter`. When i tried to display the remaining rows in next tab it throws error. I have tried `NOT IN` but it also doesn't work. I have tried `NOT EXISTS` also it shows all rows. Anyone who can answer please help. I have posted my code here. Thanks in advance.
This is the activity of first tab which displays selected rows

```
public class OnlineDevices extends Activity {
ListView listOnline;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
String count;
int conut;
TextView tvOnlineCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_online_devices);

    listOnline=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView3);
    tvOnlineCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView59);

    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String date= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    String statusQuery="select rowid _id, deviceContact from statusTable where sentTime='"+date+"'";
    Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery(statusQuery,null);

    if (cursor1.getCount()>0){
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
            String deviceNo=cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("deviceContact"));

            String device=deviceNo.substring(2, 12);

            String query="select rowid _id, userName, uSerialNo from bikeTable where uContactNo='"+device+"' AND userName IS NOT NULL";
            Cursor cursor2=db.rawQuery(query, null);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.status_item,cursor2,new String[]{"userName","uSerialNo"},new int[]{R.id.textView51,R.id.textView52});
            listOnline.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    try {
        conut = listOnline.getAdapter().getCount();
        count = String.valueOf(conut);
        tvOnlineCount.setText(count);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        int i=0;
        Toast.makeText(OnlineDevices.this,"No device is active",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tvOnlineCount.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}
```

}

Activity for second tab which display the remaining rows are

```
public class OfflineDevices extends Activity {

ListView listOffline;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
String deviceContact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_offline_devices);

    listOffline=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView4);

    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String date= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
    String query="select rowid _id, deviceContact from statusTable where sentTime='"+date+"'";
    Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor1.getCount()>0){
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
            deviceContact = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("deviceContact"));
        }
            String device=deviceContact.substring(2, 12);
            String query2="select rowid _id, userName, uSerialNo from bikeTable where userName IS NOT NULL AND uContactNo='"+device+"'";
            Cursor cursor3=db.rawQuery(query2,null);
            String query1="select rowid _id,*from bikeTable where userName IS NOT NULL NOT IN('"+query2+"')";
            Cursor cursor2=db.rawQuery(query1,null);
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.status_item,cursor2,new String[]{"userName","uSerialNo"},new int[]{R.id.textView51,R.id.textView52});
            listOffline.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Anything from Logcat? Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.realtech.st_manager_v11/com.realtech.st_manager_v11.OfflineDevices}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "9597804163": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select rowid _id, userName, uSerialNo from bikeTable where userName IS NOT NULL AND userName NOT IN('select rowid _id, userName, uSerialNo from bikeTable where uContactNo='9597804163' AND userName IS NOT NULL')`

Comment: String query2="select rowid _id, userName, uSerialNo from bikeTable where userName NOT NULL AND uContactNo='"+device+"'";
            Cursor cursor3=db.rawQuery(query2,null);
            String query1="select rowid _id,*from bikeTable where userName NOT NULL AND userName NOT IN('"+query2+"')";
            Cursor cursor2=db.rawQuery(query1,null);

Can you try above? Let me know if works.

Comment: it's not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your query. In theory the following should work:

```
String query2 = "SELECT userName FROM bikeTable WHERE userName IS NOT NULL "
        + "AND uContactNo = '" + device + "'";
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM bikeTable WHERE userName IS NOT NULL "
        + "AND userName NOT IN(" + query2 + ")";
```

Here are the differences:

1. Your original code has single quotes around `query2` inside the parentheses. This makes SQLite treat it as a string literal instead of an inner query.
2. Since `query2` is being used in a `NOT IN` expression, it needs to
   have a single result column, and it seems like `userName` is the one
   you are interested in.

I advise spending some time going through the [SQLite language](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html) pages. I'm fairly certain you can actually get the results you want using a single query that has a JOIN instead of making one query, checking the result, then making another query.

As an aside, it's considered best practice in Android to load data from a database on a background thread. Typically this is done with the [`Loader` framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). You should also be closing cursors when you are finished with them (not the ones you give to the adapters, but the ones you use just to check for an online device).